# How to change column title to top aligned together with \makecell

Tags: tables

May I know how to top align the first header column to top?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{Anaerobic treatment of antibiotic wastewater}
\label{anaerob}
\vspace{0.2cm}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{p{0.25cm}P{2.2cm}P{2.4cm}P{2.4cm}P{2.5cm}P{2.5cm}}
\hline
No&\makecell{Influent\\COD\\(mg L)}&\makecell{Influent\\antibiotics\\(mg L)}&\makecell{COD\\removal\\efficiency (\%)}&\makecell{Antibiotics\\removal\\efficiency (\%)}&Reference\\
\hline
1&9~736 to 19~862& Ampicillin 3; aureomycin 1&91&Ampicillin 67; aureomycin 51&(Zhou, 2006)\\
2&3~000 to 43~000&Penicillin&97&N/A&(Degirmentas, 2004)\\
3&127~000&Erythromycin 1 to 200&94&N/A&(Amin, 2006)\\
4&3~000&Sulfamerazine 10 to 90&69 to 89&76 to 100&(Sponza, 2007)\\
\hline

\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `makecell` offers different alignment options. Among them is `t` that aligns to the top. You can use this by replacing all occurences of `\makecell{` in your code by `\makecell[t]{`. Apart from that you might have to rethink your column widths as the table is currently much wider than the textwidth. For horizontal lines with some additional spacing around thm, you might also consider using the rules from `booktabs` that you already load.

Answer (score 1):

The vertical alignment of the column heads can be set globally with `\renewcommand{\cellalign}{tc}`. In addition, I propose this code to improve your table. It relies on `booktabs` for professional looking horizontal lines, with some vertical padding, `tabularx` to fit exactly the text width, `siunitx` to format units, numbers and ranges thereof.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx ,booktabs, caption, siunitx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\newcommand{\nl}{\newline}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2.9pt}
\renewcommand{\cellalign}{tc}
\sisetup{group-four-digits}
\caption{Anaerobic treatment of antibiotic wastewater}
\label{anaerob}
\vspace{0.2cm}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}cc>{\centering\arraybackslash}Xc*{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}@{}}
\toprule
No&\makecell{Influent COD\\(\si{\mg\L})}&\makecell{Influent antibiotics\\(\si{\mg\L})}&\makecell{COD removal\\efficiency (\%)}&\makecell{Antibiotics removal\\efficiency (\%)}&Reference\\%
\midrule
1&\numrange{9736}{19862} & Ampicillin 3; aureomycin 1&91&Ampicillin 67; aureomycin 51&(Zhou, 2006)\\
2&\numrange{3000}{43000}&Penicillin&97&N/A&(Degirmentas, 2004)\\
3&\num{127000}&Erythromycin\nl \numrange{1}{200}&94&N/A&(Amin, 2006)\\
4&\num{3000}&Sulfamerazine\nl \numrange{10}{90} & 69 to 89&\numrange{76}{100}&(Sponza, 2007)\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]